# Passing parameter to Match query in Neo4j using Spring

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to compare node name from Neo4j database with given technology name. I am doing using Spring Application.

```
@Query("MATCH (n) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i){0}' RETURN n.name")
    String getTechnology(String technologyname);
```

Request is like

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name =~ '(?i){0}'
RETURN n.name
```

with params `{0=AVM}`.

But it's returning null. However, if I do it actual technology name it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the parameter as `WHERE n.name =~ {0}`.   What's happening is that the parameter isn't substituted from within the string, so the parameter has no binding in the query, and instead you're searching for the string literal "{0}" which always fails.

If you want to pass a regex as a parameter, you'll need to put the "(?i)" part in the string getting passed, effectively letting your code decide the regex, not just a string inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the regular expression part from the parameter part like this:

```
@Query("MATCH (n) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i)' + {0} RETURN n.name")
String getTechnology(String technologyname);
```

As You'd concatenate in Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

This example from docomentation worked for me:

```
public interface ARepository extends Neo4jRepository<AnAggregateRoot, String> {

        @Query("MATCH (a:AnAggregateRoot {name: $name}) RETURN a") 
        Optional<AnAggregateRoot> findByCustomQuery(String name);
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.1.1/reference/html/#custom-queries.parameters